# Variable seems to be uninitialized when defined

Tags: php

I'm trying to do an organised setup of a website, but I've ran into an issue, on the Class file, I've used `$website['website_name'] = 'Delusion Servers';` yet when I place the variable inside a function, it says its uninitialized.

```
<?php

/*
 * Delusion Servers
 * Website access at (delusionservers.com).
 * Developed, designed and managed by Lewes B.
 * PAGE: WEBSITE.CLASS.PHP
 */

$website['website_name'] = 'Delusion Servers';

class website {

    function killPage($content){
        die("

            <h1>" . $website['website_name'] ."encountered an error</h1>

            <br /><br />" . $content . "

            ");
    }
}

$website = new Website;
?>
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution 1: Class Constant**

```
class Settings {
    const WEBSITE_NAME = 'Delusion Servers';
}

class website {

    function killPage($content){
        die("<h1>" . Settings::WEBSITE_NAME ." encountered an error</h1>
             <br /><br />" . $content);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Global Constant**

```
define("WEBSITE_NAME","Delusion Servers");
...
class website {

    function killPage($content){
        die("<h1>" . WEBSITE_NAME ." encountered an error</h1>
             <br /><br />" . $content);
    }
}
```

**Solution 3 : Class property**

```
class website {
    private $websiteName = "Delusion Servers";

    function killPage($content){
        die("<h1>" . $this->websiteName ." encountered an error</h1>
             <br /><br />" . $content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummmm why either of those?

Answer (score 3):

You function in the class is in a different scope.

Try this:

```
class website {

    function killPage($content){
        die("

            <h1>" . $this->website_name ."encountered an error</h1>

            <br /><br />" . $content . "

            ");
    }
}

$website = new Website;
$website->website_name = 'Delusion Servers';
```

Comment: Could you explain it more, since I'm utterly confused?

Answer (score 1):

```
class website {

   public $website = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->website['website_name'] = 'Delusion Servers';
    }

    function killPage($content){
        die("

            <h1>" . $this->website['website_name'] ."encountered an error</h1>

            <br /><br />" . $content . "

            ");
    }
}
```

Comment: method to set website_name ie in __contruct() would be nice too

Comment: `$website = new Website('Delusion Servers');` would be nicer! p.s. watch that __W__ ebsite class